# Obter cookies/navegadorWeb

Tags: java, cookies

eu sei que java nos fornece a possibilidade de manipular cookies, mais ai vai a pergunta.

é possível obter os cookies do navegador Web ?
se sim, a partir de qual método ?

Answer (score 3):

Veja se o método abaixo te ajuda:

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

if (cookies != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        Cookie c = cookies[i];
        System.out.println("Nome: " + c.getName());
        System.out.println("Valor: " + c.getValue());
    }
}
```

Lembrando que para obter a `request` através do JSF, basta fazer assim:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest();
```